# Program With 2 Inputs from the User to Calculate Prices of Products in C

Tags: c

I'm a total beginner to C and stuck with this rather simple program in C which needs to take input from the user in terms of product `type` and `weight`, and calculate its `price`. The program runs fine until it gets to scanning the input weight of the chosen product (returns 0) and it seems not to calculate the final price. Can somebody point what am I doing wrong here? Very much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float price;
    double cost;
    int productCode;
    int weight;
    
    printf("Enter one of the available products Potatoes, Tomatoes, Cucumbers\n");
    scanf("%d", &productCode);
    
    printf("Insert the weight of the product in kg\n>");
    scanf("%d", &weight);
    
    switch (productCode)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Product %d - Potatoes\n", productCode);
            price = 1.10;
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Product %d - Tomatoes\n", productCode);
            price = 3.40;
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Product %d = Cucumbers\n", productCode);
            price = 2.70;
        default:
            price = 0;
    }

    cost = price * weight;

    scanf("%lf\n", &cost);
    printf("Cost is %lf\n", cost);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are some sample inputs for which it behaves incorrectly? Why are you calculating `cost = price * weight;`, then the very next line overwriting `cost` with user input?

Comment: `scanf("%lf\n", &cost);` seems like it shouldn't be in this code at all.

Comment: thank you, i deleted the unnecessary code, however im still confused as to why it does not let the user input the weight, but straight away jumps to the final cost being 0 and the end of the program...

Comment: Confusing indeed... all I (not speaking for everyone) can do is speculate until you provide your sample inputs as part of a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) returns the number of arguments it matched, you should check these.

Comment: Why is `weight` an int?  I can't recall the last time I purchased a vegetable that weighed 1Kg.

Comment: thank you all!! Everything is working now. The program indeed expected numbers instead of product names. (facepalm) Thanks, im closing this thread now ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a break statement in switch case, and there was an extra piece of scanf() in the code. I have mentioned it in the comments in code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float price, weight;
    double cost;
    int productCode;
    
    
    printf("Enter one of the available products (1)Potatoes, (2)Tomatoes, (3)Cucumbers\n");
    //Better to put codes there so user knows which code is for which product
    scanf("%d", &productCode);
    
    printf("Insert the weight of the product in kg\n");
    scanf("%f", &weight);
    
    switch (productCode)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Product %d - Potatoes\n", productCode);
            price = 1.10;
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Product %d - Tomatoes\n", productCode);
            price = 3.40;
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Product %d = Cucumbers\n", productCode);
            price = 2.70;
            break; 
      /* You were also missing a break, so default case always ran and price took value of zero */
        default:
            printf("Unknown Item code\n");
            price = 0;
    }

    cost = price * weight;

   /*
    This piece of code is not needed 
    scanf("%lf\n", &cost);
    */
    printf("Cost is %lf\n", cost);
    
    return 0;
}
```